# Optimization for large (damn large) binary matrix

Tags: java, arrays, optimization

As mentioned in the title, I want to build a lattice graph representing a game map.
This lattice graph represents each pixel on the map (likely 720*1080 vertices/pixels). A pixel being a vertex object holding different values.

As expected I've got an Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

My question is the following how could I make it handle such a size?
I've already made some changes like replacing integers with booleans since booleans take less space but I;m kinda out of options.

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class GameMap {

    // We initialise our hash map which will contain the vertices and their actual point (pixel) on the map.
    // The map size is respectively height x width = number of connections / cells in the matrix.
    private HashMap<Integer, MapPixel> mapping;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private boolean[][] mapMatrix;
    private int holeRadius;
    private MapPixel start;
    private MapPixel hole;

    /**
     *  MapGenerator constructor. Builds an empty map made of MapPoint objects.
     * The map is represented by a 2D matrix made of height x width MapPoint objects.
     * Each MapPoint represents a pixel holding useful information about the terrain at that position for example.
     *  Numerous methods can be called on that object in order to change the map.
     * For example calling the GenerateTree places a tree on the map. Therefore changing the terrain height on certain points. 
     * @param width  This is the width of the map.
     * @param height This is the height of the map.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException width and height ∊ [2, ∞]
     */
    public GameMap(int width, int height) {
        if(width < 2 || height < 2) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Width = " + width + " Height = " + height + " Width and height must be greater or equal to 2!");
        }
        //Create the hash table. We want to have a MapPoint object linked to an integer. 
        //We could have chosen another type / value. The Integer was a meaningful choice 
        //since its values go way beyond the expected number of points.

        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.holeRadius = 1;

        generatePixels(this.width, this.height);
        //We then generate the map (See generate(int a, int b) for more information)
        this.mapMatrix = generate();

        System.out.println("Mapping successful");
    }

    /**
     *  Sets a tree at a random location.
     * @throws DensityException whenever the tree takes too much place.
     * TODO: Add int n for the number of trees
     */
    public void generateTrees() {
        //Hint: You are given int[][] mapMatrix and HashMap<Integer, Physics.MapPoint> mapping
        // a set of map points (vertices). Represent a tree inside the matrix.
        //To simplify your work for this phase at least we'll define a tree as 
        //a 3d rectangle with fixed x-y-z (It's up to you to choose suitable numbers)
        //(I'll send you a rough representation of what a rectangle tree looks like )
        // Your job is to change the Physics.MapPoint objects according to the coordinates.
        //What I would do is to set the height (or terrain height of the object at that position)
        //to the "tree height" but that's just one approach.
        //If something isn't clear just hit me up on gmail.

        // As you might have noticed I've let you some "space" to work in your way
        // as I know strategies can vary from on person to another.
        // What matters is that the vertex's values are changed according to the obstacles.
        //One last thing, it's up to you to throw new exceptions and / or to set boundaries
        //regarding what the user can do (or not).
        //Hence why we have chosen not to let the user defines the number of obstacles.

    }

    /**
     *  Sets a pond at a random location.
     * @throws DensityException whenever the pond takes too much place.
     * TODO: Add int n for the number of trees
     */
    public void generateWater() {
        //In the same spirit you set a rectangle of water on the map.
        //Hint: change the ground friction.
    }

    /**
     * ⛳️ Sets the hole location.
     * @param x The x position of the hole to be placed.
     * @param y The y position of the hole to be placed.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException x and y must be positive real numbers within the map coordinates.
     */
    public void setHole(int x, int y) {

        for(int i = 0; i < mapping.size(); i++) {
            if(mapping.get(i).getCoo().get_x() == x && mapping.get(i).getCoo().get_y() == y) {
                this.hole = mapping.get(i);
            }
        }
    }


    public MapPixel getHole() {
        return this.hole;
    }

    /**
     * ⛰ Sets the rock location.
     * @throws DensityException whenever the tree takes too much place.
     * TODO: Add int n for the number of trees
     */
    public void generateRocks() {
        //Hint: again you might wanna change the ground height .
    }

    /**
     *  Returns the adjacency matrix representing the game map.
     * @return mapMatrix An adjacency matrix representing the game map.
     */
    public boolean[][] getMapMatrix() {
        return this.mapMatrix;
    }


    /**
     *  Generates an adjacency matrix made of MapPoint objects.
     * The matrix actually represents a lattice graph (See below).
     * The algorithm is based on a pattern that I noticed while drawing the adjacency matrix by hand.
     * Do not try to understand it as there is there is no need to understand this algorithm in order to understand the bigger picture.
     * @see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_graph
     * @param width The map width.
     * @param height The map height.
     * @return matrix An adjacency matrix representing the lattice graph.
     */
    private boolean[][] generate() {

        boolean matrix[][] = new boolean[this.width * this.height][this.height * this.width];
        //====================================
        for (int i = 0; i < this.width * this.height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < this.height * this.width; j++) {//*3

                if ((i / 3) % 2 != (j / 3) % 2)
                    matrix[i][j] = true;
                else
                    matrix[i][j] = i % 2 == j % 2 ? false : true;
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }
    private void generatePixels(int width, int height) {
        int k = 0;
        this.mapping = new HashMap<Integer, MapPixel>();

        for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                Vector2d coordinates= new Vector2d(i, j);
                MapPixel pixel = new MapPixel(0, 0,coordinates, k);
                this.mapping.put(k, pixel);
                k++;

            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Sets the starting position.
     * @param x The x value of the starting position to be set.
     * @param y The y value of the starting position to be set.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException x and y must be positive real numbers within the map coordinates.
     */
    public void setStart(int x, int y) {
        for(int i = 0; i < mapping.size();i++) {
            if(mapping.get(i).getCoo().get_x() == x && mapping.get(i).getCoo().get_y() == y ){
                this.start = mapping.get(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isStart(MapPoint point) {
        if(point.equals(this.start)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isStart(int x, int y) {
        if(this.start.getCoo().get_x() == x && this.start.getCoo().get_x() == y) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public MapPixel getStart() {
        return this.start;
    }

    public void setHoleRadius(int radius) {
        if(radius <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("radius must be a greater or equal to 1");
        }   
    }



    //************************************
    //************DISPLAYS************
    //************************************

    /**
     *  Prints out the map's adjacency matrix. 1s indicate a connection whereas 0s mean no connection.
     */
    public void displayAdjacencyMatrix() {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.mapMatrix.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < this.mapMatrix[0].length; j++) {
                if(this.mapMatrix[i][j] == true) {
                    System.out.print(1);
                }else {
                    System.out.print(0);
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void displayPixelCoordinates() {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.height*this.width; i++) {
            System.out.println("ID = " + this.mapping.get(i).getId() + " [" + this.mapping.get(i).getCoo().get_x() + "," + this.mapping.get(i).getCoo().get_y() + "]");
        }
    }

    public void displayHeights() {
        int k = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < this.height; j++) {
                System.out.print("[" + this.mapping.get(k).getHeight() + "]");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void displayIDs() {
        int k = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < this.height; j++) {
                System.out.print("["+ k + "]");
                k++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }


    /**
    *  Prints out the vertices and their mapping. (MapPoint objects and their mapping)
    */
    public void displayMapping() {
        for(int i = 0; i < this.mapping.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(this.mapping.get(i));
        }
    }

    public void displayStartEnd() {
        int k = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < this.height; j++) {
                if(this.mapping.get(k).equals(this.start)) {
                    System.out.print("["+ "s" + "]");   
                }else if(this.mapping.get(k).equals(this.hole)){
                    System.out.print("["+ "h" + "]");   
                }else {
                    System.out.print("["+ "-" + "]");
                }
                k++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `-Xmx` to specify max heap size when running the `java` executable. See here: https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/java-xmx-xms-memory-heap-size-control/

Comment: For the map, are most of the values “empty” (or some default value) ?   If so, have you tried a “sparse array” ?

Comment: there is no free slots xD each cell contains a PixelObject.

Comment: The problem is not the “binary matrix”, i.e `boolean[][]`, but the `HashMap<Integer, MapPixel>`. Why on Earth are you using a `HashMap<Integer,…>` for a consecutive range from zero to height × width, instead of an array, the most natural choice for such a task? Besides that, you shouldn’t use the answer’s example (`-Xmx32M`) literally. 32MB are tiny by today’s standards, where even phones have several GB.